# ModuleNotFoundError: no module named '_mysql' on Python 3.8.2

Tags: server, python, mysql, python3

I am currently trying to run a python3 script, and I am running into the error "ModuleNotFoundError: no module named '_mysql' on Python 3.8.2".

I have used the same script before on this install of Ubuntu and it seemed to work just fine up until today.

I tried looking the error up and only 1 result showed up but nothing worked on that result, as expected.

Any advice? Thanks.

Comment: If you want us to audit a script, you will need to provide the script.  However, unless it's a bash script, this kind of question (about programming/scripting) might be better suited on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Install `python3-mysqldb`

You can intall this package in `Ubuntu` via this command:

```
sudo apt install python3-mysqldb
```